# net use command results in Status always as UNAVAILABLE

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hi i am trying to send the "net use" command through ssh from linux using python script. This i do using the schtasks.exe

Here is the command that i use:

```
"schtasks.exe /Create /S \"WIN-OPUQOKCV7CG\" /RU \"Administrator\" /RP \"Nbv12345\" /SC DAILY /TN cmd /TR \"mapdrivecmds.bat\" /F

"schtasks.exe /run /tn cmd
```

mapdrivecmds.bat content is:

```
net use M: \\172.17.100.197\SMBShare1 /Persistent:Yes
```

The output has the status always as "Unavailable"

Also tried the mapdrivecmds.bat with the user credentials, but this has the same problem:

```
net use M: \\172.17.100.197\SMBShare1 /User:WIN-OPUQOKCV7CG\Administrator Nbv12345 /Persistent:Yes
```

When I run the bat file locally on the machine the drive gets created without any problem. Status gives me "OK"

Can you please let me know what needs to be done. This is very tough to debug as I don't see any logs to check.

Comment: Just to reiterate there is a typo here: it should be "net use M: \\172.17.100.197\SMBShare1 /Persistent:Yes  but the problem still remains the same.

Comment: I have fixed your typo, _(in both places)_ and reformatted the code. Are you aware that there also appear to be missing/imbalanced doublequotes in both of your schtasks lines too?

Comment: I've added your comment about running locally from my deleted answer that referenced your typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out the issue here. This might help people who are trying out similar activities.
1)The thing is i have enabled SSH on Windows (Powershell ssh)
2)In the Linux system i use the Paramiko library to SSH the WINDOWS system and trigger set of powershell commands and some traffic tools
3) Some of the Traffic tools do not run as it gets killed once you execute and the control comes back. For this i thought of using the SCHTASKS.exe
4) Problem that i faced was that when i used "net use" command with the above said method it resulted in STATUS as Unavailable.
5) To overcome this i used the option `/IT` for SCHTASKS.exe. This helped. Now i see the Status as OK for the mapped network drives. Hope this helps others who are developing in similar manner.

Comment: The actual command would look like this: 'schtasks.exe /Create /S WIN-6HVMGFKE3E2 /RU "administrator" /RP "Nbv12345" /SC DAILY /TN map /TR "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\mapdrivecmds.bat" /F /IT'